# Column 'faculty.f_name' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, sqlite

```
select f.f_name,s.s_name
from faculty f, subject s
where f.f_code=s.facultycode
group by f.f_code;
```

there is an error in this nd idk what it is

Comment: What part of the error do you not understand?  Why aren't you using proper, explicit `JOIN` syntax?

Comment: sql server != sqlite. Please don't tag products not involved.

Comment: Anytime you use any sort of aggregation or `group by`. You need to aggregate the other columns involved or add them to the `group by` statement

Comment: Can you please give a summary of what you are trying to achieve with your query

Answer (score 0):

When using a group by clause in SQL Server, all non-aggregated fields must be included in the group by clause.

A few notes; I used proper join syntax, and I updated your group by clause to use the selected columns instead of the f.f_code which is not selected. With that said, all your group by clause is doing here is removing duplicate rows and could be done with a SELECT DISTINCT.

```
SELECT
    f.f_name
    ,s.s_name
FROM faculty f
JOIN subject s ON
    f.f_code=s.facultycode
GROUP BY
    f.f_name
    ,s.s_name;
```